# Two versions of a Ruby function and why there is a difference

Tags: ruby

The following two Ruby functions were written by different programmers.  The second version was 'updated' for metric users.  I am looking for an explanation  for why  the second version uses the global variable `$Wall_Lumber_Size` and the `#` Note that I am not seeking insight into the second coder's mind, but just enquiring how the `$` and the `#` work together.

**First:**

```rb
# display an input dialog and store the results in the global options hash table
def display_global_options_dialog()
    parameters = [
        # prompt, attr_name, value, enums
        [ "Wall Lumber Size", "wall.style", "2x4|2x6|2x8" ],
        [ "Wall Plate Height", "wall.height", nil ],
        [ "Wall Stud Spacing", "wall.stud_spacing", nil ],
        [ "Wall Justification  ", "window.justify",  "left|center|right" ],
        [ "Window Justification  ", "window.justify",  "left|center|right" ],
        [ "Door Justification  ", "door.justify",  "left|center|right" ],
        [ "Header Height", "header_height", nil ],
        [ "Header Size", "header_style", "2x4|2x6|4x4|4x6|4x8|4x10|4x12|4x14|6x6|6x8|6x10|8x6|8x8|8x10" ],
        [ "Roof Pitch (x/12)  ", "pitch",  nil ],
        [ "Roof Joist Spacing", 'roof.joist_spacing', nil ],
        [ "Floor Joist Spacing", 'floor.joist_spacing', nil ],
       ]
    prompts = []
    attr_names = []
    values = []
    enums = []
    parameters.each { |a| prompts.push(a[0]); attr_names.push(a[1]); values.push(HouseBuilder::BaseBuilder::GLOBAL_OPTIONS[a[1]]); enums.push(a[2]) }
    results = UI.inputbox(prompts, values, enums, 'Global Properties')
    if results
        i = 0
        attr_names.each do |name|
            eval("HouseBuilder::BaseBuilder::GLOBAL_OPTIONS['#{name}'] = results[i]")
            i = i + 1
        end
    end
    return results
end
```

**Second:**

```rb
# display an input dialog and store the results in the global options hash table
def display_global_options_dialog()

    parameters = [
        # prompt, attr_name, value, enums
        $Wall_Lumber_Size,
        #[ "Wall Lumber Size", "wall.style", "38x38|38x64|38x89|38x140|38x184|38x235|38x286|64x64|64x89|64x140|64x184|64x235|64x286|89x89|89x140|89x184|89x235|89x286" ],
        #[ "Wall Lumber Size", "wall.style", $wall_styles.join("|") ],
        [ "Wall Plate Height", "wall.height", nil ],
        [ "Wall Stud Spacing", "wall.stud_spacing", nil ],
        [ "Wall Justification  ", "window.justify",  "left|center|right" ],
        [ "Window Justification  ", "window.justify",  "left|center|right" ],
        [ "Door Justification  ", "door.justify",  "left|center|right" ],
        [ "Header Height", "header_height", nil ],
        $Header_Size,
        #[ "Header Size", "header_style", "38x38|38x64|38x89|38x140|38x184|38x235|38x286|64x64|64x89|64x140|64x184|64x235|64x286|89x89|89x140|89x184|89x235|89x286" ],
        #[ "Header Size", "header_style", $lumber_sections.join("|") ],
        #[ "Roof Pitch (x/12)  ", "pitch",  nil ],
        [ "Roof Pitch (deg°)  ", "pitch",  nil ],
        [ "Roof Joist Spacing", 'roof.joist_spacing', nil ],
            [ "Floor Joist Spacing", 'floor.joist_spacing', nil ],
        ]
    prompts = []
    attr_names = []
    values = []
    enums = []
    parameters.each { |a| prompts.push(a[0]); attr_names.push(a[1]); values.push(HouseBuilder::BaseBuilder::GLOBAL_OPTIONS[a[1]]); enums.push(a[2]) }
    results = UI.inputbox(prompts, values, enums, 'Global Properties')
    if results
        i = 0
        attr_names.each do |name|
            eval("HouseBuilder::BaseBuilder::GLOBAL_OPTIONS['#{name}'] = results[i]")
            i = i + 1
        end
    end
    return results
end
```

Comment: Lines starting with `#` are comments, meaning that those lines of code aren't actually executed. Variables starting with `$` are global variables. Other than that I don't think there's much information people can tell you here. It'd be better to just ask the programmer themselves for explanation. We can't actually see where the global variables (e.g. `$Wall_Lumber_Size`) are defined so any guesses there would be sheer conjecture

Comment: @tomfowle : Obviously the user of this function is supposed to store a suitable array into `$Wall_Lumber_Size`, before this function can be used. I can't imagine that a programmer is seriously suggesting such an interface, so perhaps this was an interim version of the function during development, and not the one which is finally supposed to be used. Actually, any use of a `$`-variable in Ruby needs really good justification. Good uses of globals are rare.

Comment: `eval("HouseBuilder::BaseBuilder::GLOBAL_OPTIONS['#{name}'] = results[i]")` where `result[i]` coming from UI input box - that can be fun to play with, for example type `rm -rf /` in input box ;)

Comment: Seeing global variables here is not a good sign, those are usually a huge hassle, and also the use of `eval` is really quite terrifying and completely unnecessary in this case. Additionally, combining a bunch of statements on the same line using `;` is just making a giant mess of things.

Comment: `HouseBuilder::BaseBuilder::GLOBAL_OPTIONS[name] = results[i]` does what you want without the completely reckless use of `eval`. Stay away from `eval` unless you have an extremely compelling use case that cannot be solved using another approach, of which Ruby almost always has a solution.

Comment: You can also do `each_with_index` and avoid all the junk with manually incrementing `i`.

Comment: This code needs a lot more refactoring to bring it into the realm of *maintainability* to be honest. For example, if "parameters" is fixed, it should be a constant. You're declaring it here each time, then painfully transforming it, each and every time this method is called. Declare it once. Transform it into the quirky form the `inputbox` needs once. Keep those at the ready as constants.

Answer (score 1):

Lines prepended with `#` are annotations (comments in Ruby) which are ignored at parse time.

Global Variables defined with `$` are variables that may be accessed from anywhere in the program regardless of scope

As Max pointed out in his comment, without having access to the code we don't know what the global variable `$Wall_Lumber_Size` holds. However, you can look at the definition and see what its value actually is.

The global variable (`$`) and comments (`#`) are not related whatsoever.

Comment: "Lines prepended with `#` are annotations […]" – No, they are not, they are *comments*. Ruby does not have annotations. You might be thinking of *directives* aka *magic comments*, but those can *only* appear at the beginning of a script. "[…] which are ignored at runtime." – They are ignored at *parse time*, which is even *before* runtime. In fact, they are literally treated as whitespace by the parser.

Comment: You are right. I know that Ruby doesn't use the word 'annotations'. I wasn't trying to use ruby notation, but explain what they represent with other word. Regarding when it is ignored, thanks for pointing that out.